# Execute root commands to link before starting execution

Tags: root-framework

Is there a way to tell `root` to execute (say) the following commands at the start?

```
.L /usr/lib/libgsl.so
.L /usr/lib/libgslcblas.so
```

I find it convenient as I have to execute this every time I start root. My .C file has uses these libraries.

I found an option `-e` but I cannot use it for more than one line of commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just add the following into a `~/.rootlogon.C` (or create one in case you don't have it):

```cpp
{
// old content here
  gROOT->ProcessLine(".L /usr/lib/libgsl.so");
  gROOT->ProcessLine(".L /usr/lib/libgslcblas.so");
}
```